# extract a sub-array from a multidimentional array based on the array key

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Say I have the following PHP array:

```
$test = array(

    'bob' => array(
        'age' => '23',
        'region' => 'Yorkshire',
        'salary' => '£21,000'
    ),

    'sarah' => array(
        'age' => '42',
        'region' => 'Yorkshire',
        'salary' => '£60,000'
    ),

    'jim' => array(
        'age' => '28',
        'region' => 'Yorkshire',
        'salary' => '£35,000'
    )
)
```

Is it possible to pull a sub array from the multidimentional array using the array key as a reference? I can pull a single sub array using array_slice() however I believe it requires an integer for length and for offset. I was hoping for something like $new_array = array_slice('jim') where

```
$new_array = array(
    'age' => '28',
    'region' => 'Yorkshire',
    'salary' => '£22,000'
)
```

thanks.

Comment: You can't have 2 values in array with the same key 'jim'

Comment: Sorry, I know this just a poor bit of copy and paste on my behalf, I'll edit to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
$new_array = $test['jim'];
```

(assuming that $test is a valid array, meaning your keys in $test are unique, which they are not in your example)

Comment: Thankyou! I think I overcomplicated this one massively, am I right in thinking that I can use a variable in the array key like this $new_array = $test[$user];